# grunt serve fails - Insecure operation - file?

Tags: ruby, gruntjs, yeoman

I use in my project Yeoman and suddenly grunt serve is aborting on this task: concurrent:server. Here are errors:

```
Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
Warning: /Users/ograbek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:62:in `file?': Insecure operation - file? (SecurityError)
    from /Users/ograbek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in contains_requirable_file?'
    from /Users/ograbek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:62:in `each'
    from /Users/ograbek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:62:in `any?'
    from /Users/ograbek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:62:in `block in contains_requirable_file?'
    from /Users/ograbek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:60:in `each'
    from /Users/ograbek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:60:in `any?'
    from /Users/ograbek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:60:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /Users/ograbek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Users/ograbek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
    from /Users/ograbek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
    from /Users/ograbek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Users/ograbek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
    from /Users/ograbek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/ograbek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /Users/ograbek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:9:in `<main>' Use --force to continue.
```

If I use --force flag the server starts up but it can't find stylesheets any more. I use:
grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.5

*Edit*: It seems like the problem with grunt-contrib-compass. When I just run grunt compass I get the same errors.

*Edit*: When I run grunt serve --verbose I see:

```
Running "compass:server" (compass) task
Verifying property compass.server exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: sassDir="app/styles", cssDir=".tmp/styles", generatedImagesDir=".tmp/images/generated", imagesDir="app/images", javascriptsDir="app/scripts", fontsDir="app/styles/fonts", importPath="app/bower_components", httpImagesPath="/images", httpGeneratedImagesPath="/images/generated", httpFontsPath="/styles/fonts", relativeAssets=false, assetCacheBuster=false, raw="Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n", debugInfo
Warning: Command failed: /Users/ograbek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:62:in `file?': Insecure operation - file? (SecurityError)
```

File: [no files] - maybe this is a problem?

Comment: I checked security level in Ruby ($SAFE). It is set to default level => 0. So it shouldn't throw this exception at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was problem with my environment. Grunt was run with wrong permissions.

Comment: Hey can you share how did you fix the grunt permissions problem? I have the same error. Thanks